# Best way to handle ENUM type in Laravel

Tags: laravel, enums

I am using Laravel and I want to know the best way to handle ENUM type in my migrations and models. I have seen two approaches, one is to create a column with ENUM type in the migration like this:

```
$table->enum('type', ['pending', 'active', 'rejected']);
```

and the second approach is to create a ENUM class and use it to cast the column in the model like this:

```
class ProductStatusEnum
{
    const Pending = 'pending';
    const Active = 'active';
    const Rejected = 'rejected';
}

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'status' => ProductStatusEnum::class
    ];
}
```

Which of these approaches is the best and why?

Comment: they are not mutually exclusive

Answer (score 0):

The second approach of using a custom ENUM class to cast the column in the model is considered a better practice. This approach has several advantages over the first approach of using an ENUM column in the migration:

**Readability**: Using a custom ENUM class makes your code more readable and self-documenting. It makes it easier for other developers to understand the different possible values of the column.

**Type safety**: Using a custom ENUM class allows you to use type hints in your code, making it easier to catch errors at compile-time rather than runtime.

**Maintainability**: If you need to add or remove values from the ENUM in the future, you can do so in one place, in the ENUM class, rather than having to make changes in multiple places throughout your code.

**Flexibility**: Using a custom ENUM class allows you to add additional methods or properties to the ENUM to support its use in your application.
Overall, the second approach is a more robust and flexible way of handling ENUM types in your Laravel application. It's a good idea to use custom ENUM classes wherever possible in your models.

Comment: @moritz, you realize you're just polishing chatgpt, right? see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/11107541